# Expected indent error after def statement

Tags: python, function, syntax

So this happens and I have tried retyping it the def statement. How can I fix this? I don't know when it started happening or why it happens but I know that I got it working once I think from restarting the program. This is python btw

https://i.stack.imgur.com/5A7kS.png

Comment: what programming language?

Comment: Given what you've written, how can you **possibly** expect anyone to be able to help you?

Comment: Have you seen the image? @Alexander

Comment: @Beatenberg Code in images is horrible. Hard to copy - no-one is going to bother copying out your code to try it themselves. Please post the code as part of your question, along with the associated stack trace for the error (if you have one). Other details such as Python version, IDE, OS etc also help sometimes.

Comment: @Beatenberg There wasn't an image in your post until your edit, and even still, I'm not going to waste my time transcoding the image because you're too lazy to paste the code itself.

Comment: @AndrewGuy I figured it was better to put it in an image because I wanted to show the error. But I understand what you and Alexandar are saying. Again was not trying to be lazy but rather so you would not have to type it.

Comment: Why is this still getting downvoted even though it's been answered? Yes, it was a very bad question and now have to wait a week to ask another question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should make sure your indentation is uniform (always 4 spaces). Starting with `if Submit == "yes":`, your lines have one extra space. This will be easier to do if you use a better IDE than IDLE, which will automatically highlight and label problems like this. Some good alternatives are Spyder (which is free), and PyCharm (which is free for students).